# Correctly return Promise value from recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a function that should to build route from start to destination.

```
function solve(start, end, fetchRouts): Promise<string[] | string>;
```

There also function that returns Promise with reachable points from current:

```
function fetchRouts(departurePoint: string): Promise<string[]>;
```

I'm trying to solve using a recursive function. But i can't return the value correctly. Second [*] then is visited 3 times, but returns first time, *result* is undefined here, so returns 'no ticket';

Inside **solve**:

```
const getRoute = (routes, stations) => {
    return routes.then((next) => {
        const temp = [...next];
        while (temp.length !== 0) {
            const current = temp[0];

            const copyStations = [...stations];
            copyStations.push(current);

            if (current === end)
                return Promise.resolve({ result: copyStations, end: true }); //how to throw result from here

            getRoute(fetchRouts(current), copyStations).then(result => {
                if (result && result.end)
                    return result;
            });
            temp.splice(0, 1); // delete station,  because they were on it
        }
    }).then(result => { // [*]
        if (result && result.end) {
            return Promise.resolve(result.result); // to here
        }
        return Promise.resolve('no ticket');
    })
}

return getRoute(fetchRouts(start), [start]);
```

a lil function description: *first argument* - `Promise<string[]>`, contains next stations, also accumulate route (*second argument*). I split the array and look for the next available one for each station.  If available station exists, go to it. If station is destination, return Promise. idk how return its correctly.

Comment: Can you use async/await? That'll make it easier to read. You need to return the result of getRoute when you call it recursively. For your base case, you'll probably need to return an empty array at some point.

Comment: https://fireship.io/courses/javascript/interview-graphs/ depth-first search walks you through this. Difference is you need to do it asynchronously.

Comment: @TrevorDixon , need to solve without async/await

Comment: Instead of `getRoute(fetchRouts(...))`, you need something like `return fetchRouts(...).then(routes => { return getRoute(routes, ...); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is graph traversal. You can either do breadth-first or depth-first search, but since you want to do it recursively, depth-first makes sense. Any time you call a function that returns a promise, you need to return it and then process the return value in the `then` handler.

```
function solve(start, end, fetchRouts) {
  function getRoute(start, visited = new Set()) {
    visited.add(start);
    return fetchRouts(start).then(nexts => {
      for (const next of nexts) {
        if (next === end) {
          const route = Array.from(visited);
          route.push(end);
          return route;
        }
        if (!visited.has(next)) {
          return getRoute(next, visited);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return getRoute(start);
}
```

Adapted from https://fireship.io/courses/javascript/interview-graphs/ depth-first search section.

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
function solve(start, end, fetchRouts) {
  function getRoute(start, visited = new Set()) {
    visited.add(start);
    return fetchRouts(start).then(nexts => {
      for (const next of nexts) {
        if (next === end) {
          const route = Array.from(visited);
          route.push(end);
          return route;
        }
        if (!visited.has(next)) {
          return getRoute(next, visited);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return getRoute(start);
}

const dests = {"PHX":["LAX","JFK"],"BKK":["MEX","LIM"],"OKC":["JFK"],"JFK":["PHX","OKC","HEL","LOS"],"LAX":["PHX","MEX"],"MEX":["LAX","BKK","LIM","EZE"],"EZE":["MEX"],"HEL":["JFK"],"LOS":["JFK"],"LAP":[],"LIM":["MEX","BKK"]};
const fetchRoutes = async (station) => dests[station];

solve('PHX', 'BKK', fetchRoutes).then(route => console.log(route));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but here are some problems: this doesn't work for all examples. Solution is to create a clone of visited for each function call and work with it, also remove return here 'return getRoute(next, visited)'; Thanks anyway)

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
function solve(start, end, fetchRouts) {

const getRoute = (start, visited = new Set()) => {

    const clone = new Set(visited);
    clone.add(start);

    return fetchRouts(start).then(nexts => {
        for (const next of nexts) {
            if (next === end) {
                const route = Array.from(clone);
                route.push(end);
                return route;
            }
            if (!clone.has(next)) {
                getRoute(next, clone);
            }
        }
    });
}

return getRoute(start).then(result =>
    result ? Promise.resolve(result) : Promise.resolve('no ticket')
);
```

};

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).